# Performing a calculation on a DataFrame based on condition in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with COVID data and am trying to control for population and show incidence per 100,000.

I have one DataFrame with population:

```
**Country**  **Population**
China        1389102
Israel       830982
Iran         868912
```

I have a second DataFrame showing COVID data:

```
**Date**      **Country**  **Confirmed**
01/Jan/2020      China          8
01/Jan/2020      Israel         3
01/Jan/2020      Iran           2
02/Jan/2020      China          15
02/Jan/2020      Israel         5
02/Jan/2020      Iran           5
```

I wish to perform a calculation on my COVID DataFrame using info from the population DataFrame. That is to say, to normalise cases per 100,000 for each data via:

(Chinese Datapoint/Chinese Population) * 100,000

Likewise for my other countries.

I am stumped on this one and not too sure do I achieve my result via grouping data, zipping data, etc.
Any help welcome.

Edit: I should have added that confirmed cases are cumulative as each day goes on. So for example, I wish to performed for Jan 1st for China: (8/china population)*100000 and like wise for Jan 2nd, Jan 3rd, Jan 4th... And again, likewise for each country. Essentially performing a calculation to the entire DataFrame based on data in another DataFrame.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @MayankPorwal The exact COVID dataframe which I called my 'second DataFrame', with the confirmed cases controlled per 100,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge 2 dataframes and perform the operation:

```
# Define the norm operation
def norm_cases(cases, population):
    return (cases/population)*100

# If the column name for country is same in both dataframes
covid_df.merge(population_df, on='country_column', how='left')

# For different col names
covid_df.merge(population_df, left_on='covid_country_column', right_on='population_country_column', how='left')

covid_df['norm_cases'] = covid_df.apply(lambda x: norm_cases(x['cases_column'], x['population_column']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dataframes are called `df1` and `df2` and by "Datapoint" you mean the column `**Confirmed**`:

```
normed_cases = (
    df2.reset_index().groupby(['**Country**', '**Date**']).sum()['**Confirmed**'] 
    / df1.set_index('**Country**')['**Population**'] * 100000)
```

- reset the index of `df2` to make the date a column (only applicable if `**Date**` was the index before)
- Group by country **and date** and sum the groups to get the total cases per country **and date**
- set country as index to the first df `df1` to allow country-index oriented division
- divide by population

Comment: It won't work since the inidices does not match at the same country appear several times in `df2`

Comment: Now it should work, didn't see that there were duplicates.

Comment: @Scotty1- Thanks for the response. This does work, but it gives an overall figure. I was looking moreso for say for China for Jan 1st: (8/china pop)*100000. For Jan 2nd: (15/china pop)*100000 etc for each data and country in my dataframe. Nice approach though.

Comment: You are welcome and may also upvote my answer for the effort. :) Could you please integrate the additional information in your question? Without providing full information, it is highly unlikely to be able to answer your question. :)

Comment: I included the date in my answer. Still no idea if that is what you want, but you should take a look at it. :)

Comment: @Scotty1- That looks like it would work I'm sure. I posted my own response using a combination of response I received here however. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I took an approach combining many of your suggestions. Step one, I merged my two dataframes. Step two, I divided my confirmed column by the population. Step three, I multiplied the same column by 100,000. There probably is a more elegant approach but this works.

```
covid_df = covid_df.merge(population_df, on='Country', how='left')

covid_df["Confirmed"] = covid_df["Confirmed"].divide(covid_df["Population"], axis="index")

covid_df["Confirmed"] = covid_df["Confirmed"] *100000
```

Comment: Let me be honest: Imho it is far from good etiquette to ask a question, wait for answers and then answer the question on your own based on other answers **without giving any acknoledgement** for the answers provided. You should know that there are many on SO, who look at how someone handled previous questions before answering new ones. So if you want to keep getting a steady flow of good answers, you should mind that...

Comment: @Scotty1- I'm not sure what you're talking about. I upvoted your own post, and marked another post as the solution as it was *a* solution, which I then refined.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Dataframe with population as df_pop, and  Covid data as df_data.

```
# Set index country of df_pop
df_pop = df_pop.set_index(['Country'])
# Norm value
norm = 100000
# Calculate norm cases
df_data['norm_cases'] = [((conf/df_pop.loc[country].Population )*norm
                         for (conf, country) in zip(df_data.Confirmed,df_data.Country) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df1.set_index('Country').join(df2.set_index('Country'))` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), then it will be easy for you to perform this actions.